# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02] when changing password using Drupal Commons 7

Tags: users, 7

I'm new in using Drupal Commons 7. I've been trying to register a user in the membership site that I'm making but this comes out whenever the user tries to change his password:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '[name].oauth_common_consumer' doesn't exist: SELECT c.csid AS csid, c.consumer_key AS consumer_key, c.secret AS secret, c.configuration AS configuration, pc.created AS created, pc.changed AS changed, pc.uid AS uid, pc.name AS name, pc.context AS context, pc.callback_url AS callback_url FROM {oauth_common_consumer} c LEFT OUTER JOIN {oauth_common_provider_consumer} pc ON pc.csid = c.csid WHERE (c.csid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => ) in DrupalOAuthConsumer::loadById() (line 173 of /home4/[name]/public_html/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/oauth/includes/DrupalOAuthConsumer.inc).

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This indicates a database table is missing. Given that the error happens in the oauth module itself, I would assume the error is not caused by incompatible modules working together. I can think of three possible causes:

1. You need to clear the caches.
   Whenever you have a problem like this in Drupal, you should try clearing the caches. This can be done by going to *Administer > Site Configuration > Performance* on your site.
2. You need to run some database updates.
   When you upgrade modules, they sometime needs to run some update code which can, for instance, add new tables or change table definitions. This can be done by going to `/update.php` on your site.
3. There was an error when installing this module.
   If neither of the possibilities above work, you might want to try to disable this module, and re-enable it to see if there is any problem during installation.
   **Warning**: this will probably require you to disable other modules, and might cause a loss of data. Try this on a copy of the site.